# How can I run performance testing on a unit test in VS2010?

Tags: performance, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, instrumentation

Fairly straightforward question... I want to run performance metrics (instrumentation tests, to be precise) on a unit test. How can I set this up? The performance monitor wizard in VS2010 asks for a DLL or EXE to monitor, and I don't know how to set this up. Thanks.